# How can I decode this string which is represented as unicode?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, python-unicode

I get `s` when trying to parse a web page by readability(Python 2.7 on Windows 10, Sublime Text 2/cmd)

```
>>> import requests
>>> from readability import Document
>>>
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.gamersky.com/news/201806/1064930.shtml')
>>> doc = Document(response.text.encode("utf-8"))
>>> print doc.title()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
>>> print doc.title().encode("utf-8")
lots of messy codes
>>> print doc.title().encode("utf-16")
lots of messy codes
>>> print doc.title().encode("gbk")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'gbk' codec can't encode character u'\xe3' in position 0: illegal multibyte sequence
```

I found I can never print out `doc.title()`, so I looked into `doc.title()` by running

```
s = repr(doc.title())
print type(doc.title())
print s
```

The result is very strange

```
<type 'unicode'>
u'\xe3\x80\x8a\xe5\xa5\x87\xe5\xbc\x82\xe4\xba\xba\xe7\x94\x9f\xe3\x80\x8b\xe5\x9b\xa2\xe9\x98\x9f\xe6\x96\xb0\xe4\xbd\x9c\xe3\x80\x8a\xe8\xb6 \xe8\x83\xbd\xe9\x98\x9f\xe9\x95\xbf\xe3\x80\x8b\xe5 \x8d\xe8\xb4\xb9\xe4\xb8\x8b\xe8\xbd\xbd \xe5\xb0\x8f\xe7\x94\xb7\xe5\xad\xa9\xe7\x9a\x84\xe8\x8b\xb1\xe9\x9b\x84\xe6\xa2\xa6\xe6\x83\xb3 _ \xe6\xb8\xb8\xe6\xb0\x91\xe6\x98\x9f\xe7\xa9\xba GamerSky.com'
```

It seem that `s` is actually encoded in multibytes, because when I run

```
 print '\xe3\x80...'
```

And it prints

```
《奇异人生》团队新作《? 能队长》? ?费下载 小男孩的英雄梦想 _ 游民星空 GamerSky.com
```

Where the accurate title is

```
《奇异人生》团队新作《超能队长》免费下载 小男孩的英雄梦想 _ 游民星空 GamerSky.com
```

Though there are some characters still missing, but the result convince me that the `\xe3` should not be represented as a unicode form.
After some searching, I found the following code helps, but there are still some missing characters.

```
>>> print s.encode("raw_unicode_escape")
《奇异人生》团队新作《? 能队长》? ?费下载 小男孩的英雄梦想 _ 游民星空 GamerSky.com
```

My questions are:

1. Why is this problem probably happen? Is the `encode("raw_unicode_escape")` solution neat?
   When I run the following codes, it works

   ```
   >>> import requests
   >>> from readability import Document
   >>>
   >>> response = requests.get('https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:%E9%A6%96%E9%A1%B5')
   >>> doc = Document(response.text.encode("utf-8"))
   >>> print doc.title()
   维基百科，自由的百科全书
   ```
2. How to handle the missing characters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you use `response.text`, it makes a guess at what the encoding is when decoding `response.content` into unicode. In this case its guess is incorrect. You have to force the encoding by setting `response.encoding` to `'utf-8'`, per [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-content).

```
import requests
from readability import Document
response = requests.get('http://www.gamersky.com/news/201806/1064930.shtml')
response.encoding = 'utf-8'
doc = Document(response.text)
print doc.title()
```

And this prints:

```
《奇异人生》团队新作《超能队长》免费下载 小男孩的英雄梦想 _ 游民星空 GamerSky.com
```

Comment: That generates a `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-34: ordinal not in range(128)` error

Comment: I just edited my answer. You should decode `response.content` instead.

Comment: Yes, that works now. I now get the point here, `response.content` returns a `str`, `response.text` returns a `unicode`, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. The problem is that when you use `response.text`, it makes a guess at what the encoding is. In this case it is incorrect. You have to correct it by setting `response.encoding = 'utf-8'`. I've updated my code above to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `response.content`

**Ex:**

```
>>> import requests
>>> from readability import Document
>>>
>>> response = requests.get('http://www.gamersky.com/news/201806/1064930.shtml')
>>> doc = Document(response.content)
>>> print doc.title()
```